# The best way to toggle between modes using UICollectionView like in Photos

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Basically, I am using UICollectionView and want to allow users to switch between 2 modes. The first, will allow users to tap each item and see more details about it. The second, will allow users to select multiple items and either delete them or share them. I want something similar that is possible to do in the standard "Photos" app.

The items on the navigation bar and on the tab bar will be changed based on the current mode.

My first idea is to use the same controller and just replace items in the navigation bar and the tab bar accordingly based on the current mode.

My second idea is to use 2 different controllers with different sets of buttons on both the navigation bar and the tab bar. The only thing I was planning to move the same UICollectionView back and forward dependently on the current mode so that the current scrolling state of the collection stay the same.

I may be wrong in both of my approaches. I am new in iOS and would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: This question is too broad to really get a good answer here, but I'd start with your single-controller implementation. No need to throw multiple controllers into the mix based on what you said. It will introduce around as many problems as it solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't use two separate view-controllers. In fact, the problem statement suggests that you *shouldn't*, because it's just two ways (modes) of presenting the same view.

The way I would solve this problem is:

1. Have an instance variable in the view-controller (either an enum or a boolean) that represents the current mode
2. Use a UIView transition, on change of the mode, to add/remove buttons from the `UINavigationBar` (at the top) and the `UIToolBar` (not UITabBar - Tab Bars are used specifically to switch between view-controllers in a UITabBarController) at the bottom.
3. Also, on change of the mode, reload the Collection View with or without animation.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the better than a new controller. Thanks for your answer.